# In Aerospike, is it possible to "chain gets" with a UDF?

Tags: aerospike

I see examples in the documentation where it's possible to take a record, or stream of records from a set, and perform some action. I'd like to take a record, retrieve an identifier from that record, lookup that identifer in another set, and return the contents of a bin from the second set. It's effectively a join, e.g.

```
function chained_get(rec)
    if aerospike:exists( rec ) then
        local other_id = rec.other_id
--      how to return the result of: 'SELECT some_bin FROM namespace.some_bin WHERE PK = other_id'
    end
    return result
end
```

I realize that would be easy to do on the client/application side, but I'd like to avoid the network 'chatter' if possible and 'chain' the get requests inside Aerospike.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer is no, Aerospike Server does not support such joins (yet?) where the server itself takes an active part. But there are workarounds for near single round-trip latencies:**

The issue with a join in a distributed database is that the other record might be on another node in the cluster. But depending on what you are trying to do, it's highly likely that you can do so with other tools that Aerospike offers. One powerfull feature for example is the secondary index functionality. You could e.g. have a user and a set of orders (records). To avoid having to lookup the user first and then issue a batch get on all orders, you could issue the user get and a query that gets you all records having user id = xyz in a bin that is indexed in parallel and merge on client-side. Drawback is that all nodes will receive an query because it's unknown where the orders are located and that you need some 45-70 bytes RAM per secondary index entry. However, you should benchmark whether this performs better than your 2 round-trip alternative because it depends on priority of queries, secondary index size and such..

Let me know if that approach solves your problem or what requirements you have and we can help you achieving this. It might be interesting if you add benchmarking results if you try both.

Answer (score 3):

A record UDF cannot access other records, and a stream UDF can only work on records streamed in from a scan or as the results matched by a secondary index query.  JOINs can be implemented on the application-side.